# Is there any possible function or composite that can give me this result?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis

I have two analytic functions $x$ and $y$ in the form of $h(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. Is there any possible combination of any kind of  exterior functions I can apply to $h(x,y)$ such that the right-hand expression then becomes just $x+y$?

Or otherwise, is there a function $k$ such that $k(h(x,y))=x+y$?

Error function it, exponential integral it, gamma function it, inverse fresnel integral it if you have to, doesn't matter to me just as long as there is some combination of known functions that are continuous over a non-singleton and/or non-empty domain that can do it.

Comment: Consider the simple case $f(x)=x=g(x)$, here $h(x)=2x^2$ and this function is not injective, hence we cannot invert it (well up to a $\pm$ we can).

Comment: That's a pretty cop-out response. It's not relevant because all that matters is the algebra. The only one who needs to worry about the grunt work of the domain over which it is applied is me. I mean c'mon, I mentioned the inverse Fresnel integral, that has countably infinite branches as an inverse. I mentioned the gamma function, it is definitely not 1-1 nor even onto over either the positive half-plane or negative half-plane. I explicitly said you have access to such functions.

Comment: I think it unlikely that you can recover  the sum of two functions from the sum of their squares without significantly more information. If you [edit] the question to provide some context - some of that information - perhaps we can help. Without it, I don't think you should complain about elementary counterxamples.

Comment: The focus is the terms, you shouldn't need any more information. I made them $x$ and $y$ instead since you seem distracted by wanting to know more about the functions used to construct the problem even though it is irrelevant to the question. Even the functions $h$ and $k$ are merely proxies for the common idea of manipulating both sides with balancing, the idea is completely trivial, I've simply opened it up to include unusual answers beyond what one encounter in high school courses.

Comment: I was just trying to help and i think considering simple examples before using heavy math artillery is key to understanding why it is or isn't possible. In the current formulation i do not think it is possible. 

Consider the following argument.
Suppose that this is in fact possible to do for all such functions. Consider function $x$ and $y$ as well as $-x$ and $-y$. Since $h(x,y)=h(x,-y)=h(-x,y)=h(-x,-y)$ it is unclear wheter $k$ should return $x+y$,$x-y$,$-x+y$ or $-x-y$.

Comment: I think you are drastically overlooking what the goal is here. If you do not want to take the time to understand what I am telling you, then I can't help you. I will tell you again in a slightly different way: it does not matter to the problem whether one value is mapped to countably many values anymore than that arcsin(x) or arctan(x) has "infinite images" over the reals matters. We still can call arcsin(x) and arctan(x) functions. The goal is to get to the point where we can decide to make those kinds of restrictions at all, so nitpicking domain/co-domain restrictions is off topic.

Comment: "If you do not want to take the time to understand what I am telling you, then I can't help you." That's not how it works. Instead, if you're not being understood, it's up to you to take the time to understand the points people bring up in the comments and improve your question (if you can) so that it is possible for at least a few people to understand what you're asking. An alternative possibility to consider is that people actually *do* understand what you're asking but you are in fact asking for something that doesn't exist.

Comment: It is how it works because I've addressed all the points you've brought up, you just refuse to aknowledge what I tell you when I tell you that the points you've brought up are not important. You don't want to take the time to understand the problem because it looks easy to you, you want it to be easy because the topic is trivial and that's not my responsibility. The reality is the points you brought up don't matter to this question, and if you refuse to listen to me when I tell you that, then that's your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose such function exists, i.e. $$k(x^2+y^2)=x+y$$
Then,
$$k(25)=3+4=7$$
Also,
$$k(25)=\sqrt{20}+\sqrt{5}=3\sqrt{5}$$
A function cannot map same argument to different images. Hence, such a function cannot exist.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: I don't see that this alone should be a concern of anyone. Take a function that maps x^2 to x. It "maps the same argument to two different images", being +sqrt(x) and -sqrt(x), but in simple problem solving, no one cares and we still call it a function because anyone can arbitrarily restrict the range to either [0,infinity) or (-infinity, 0]. Your point is moot, even for a function that maps a single argument to countably infinite images like arcsin(x). Is arcsin(x) a function? We can make it one. What we investigate here is the act of applying such a function assuming we can "make it one".

Comment: @cheesemonkey102 what I want to say is that, you cannot make it a function. If $a+b$ is a solution, then $\sqrt{a+\varepsilon }+\sqrt{b-\varepsilon }$ is also a solution for all $\varepsilon\in (0,b)$ assuming $a$ and $b$ positive. This way you have uncountably infinite number of images for a single argument. Any kind of restriction you are talking about will not work in this case.

Comment: In fact, you can prove that $\forall x\in [0,\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{2}}], x+\sqrt{\alpha-x^2}$ is a distinct solution of $k(\alpha)$ and this is an exhaustive set of solutions.

Comment: I think it is worth it to mention specifically an uncountable number of images, not merely 2, and I can appreciate specifically that point. In that case, how do we know an otherwise continuous a function capable of performing this operation can't simply be characterized as having an asymtote at the input of $x^2+y^2$?

Comment: What do you mean by this "asymptote" thing?